# Paperclip problems when trying to set up a size for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, size, paperclip

I am using paperclip in my rails app. The gem comes with a this set up in my user controller :

```
has_attached_file :licencepicture,
 styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
```

I tried to set up a new size for my pictures doing this :

```
 styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>", large:"500x500>" }
```

but this just doesnt work, the image doesnt display at all. But medium and thumb work just fine !

Thanks

Comment: "but this just doesnt work, the image doesnt display at all." - what are you doing for display large version of image?

Answer (score 0):

note that only new images appear in new style "large" and added images before do not exist in style "large", for solve you need write command for imagemagik for make copies from medium style